# Spring Webflow IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, spring-webflow-2

My ultimate goal is to have a model with annotations and do validations on form inputs. I have tried that with writing some validators but it didn't work (The form would not even show fields where I could enter sp there was nothing to test the validation on), so I was trying it from the start in little steps. As a first step I just want to make the model binding work before I start any sort of validation.

As a simple try, I used the mailItemModel form http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-spring-web-flow-swf/

I have added the following line to the servlet-config.xml, which is linked in the web.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.kumo.**" />
```

I had that from another tutorial and I kind of thought this would make is scan the whole package and I would not need to specify all the models in variables explicitly. I get the titular error.
I have also tried adding "@Component" to the model class. But that didn't change anything.

Into the flow XML I then tried adding

```
<var name="MailItemModel" />
```

as from the above linked tutorial. I got the error, that element var" requires a "class" attribute. So I make it this instead:

```
<var name="MailItemModel" class="com.mypackage.kumo.model.MailItemModel" />
```

but that just trows the very same error as before.

My flow looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    start-state="Start">

    <var name="MailItemModel" class="com.mypackage.kumo.model.MailItemModel" />

    <view-state id="Start" view="/Search" model="MailItemModel">
        <transition on="entered" to="temp" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="SubEnde" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="temp" view="/End" />

    <view-state id="SubEnde" view="/Start" />    
</flow>
```

Search.jsp (Form excerpt)

```
<form:form method = "post" modelAttribute = "mailItemModel">
      Mail Username: <form:input path="username" />
         <br />
       <input type="submit" name="_eventId_entered" value="Entered" />
       <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form:form>
```

Start.jsp and End.jsp are just static jsps with some lorem ipsum content.

The Stacktrace:

```
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mailItemModel' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(Search_jsp.java:559)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(Search_jsp.java:522)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_dsx_005fcontent_002dbox_005f0(Search_jsp.java:478)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_dsx_005fcontent_005f0(Search_jsp.java:439)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_dsx_005fhtml_002dbody_005f0(Search_jsp.java:375)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspx_meth_dsx_005fhtml_005f0(Search_jsp.java:293)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Search_jsp._jspService(Search_jsp.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have looked into other posts of the same error, but they all use @requestmapping to an URL in a controller, but since I am using Webflow, I don't (and can't it would seem) use controllers, so it didn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things flawed in your configuration

1. Your name of the model is wrong
2. Your base package is a ant-style expression

In your configuration you named your model object `MailItemModel` (notice the **M**)

```
<var name="MailItemModel" class="com.mypackage.kumo.model.MailItemModel" />
```

In your view it is named `mailItemModel` (notice the **m**).

```
<form:form method = "post" modelAttribute = "mailItemModel">
```

Either change it in your flow configuration to `mailItemModel` or in your view use `MailItemModel` the names have to match, including the casing.

Regarding your configuration.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.kumo.**" />
```

The `base-package` property is just that the name(s) of the base packages to scan. It doesn't take an ant-style expression. Remove the ending `.**`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.kumo" />
```

A final note the use of `<context:component-scan … />` already implies `<context:annotation-config />` so you can remove that line of configuration.

Comment: Thanks, fixing the M-m issue solved the problem. Through I still need to declare the variable wiht the full classpath. So is the component-scan just there for the annotations automatically? Meaning, in case the classpath may ever change, I would have to change every single flow xml file, which uses the model, manually?

Comment: For component-scanning see the Spring Reference Guide. As for your model if you want flow-scoped models you will have to declare them in your flow.